# how to scrape all items of a page using a loop

Tags: python, for-loop, beautifulsoup

i'm trying to scrape and list 24 items from a certain website. instead, it shows the same item 24 times.

to get the first price i did this:

```py
gamma_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(gamma_html, "html.parser")
hout = page_soup.findAll ("article",{"class":"mc-product-tile product-online-state-for_sale_not_orderable_in_stock product-state-for_sale"})
print len(hout)
i = 0
contain = hout[i]
brand = contain.div.img["alt"]
price = contain.findAll("div",{"class":"product-price-current"})
price = str(price).split("<div class=\"product-price-current\">")[1]
price = price.split(".</div>")[0]
price_2 = contain.findAll("span",{"class":"product-price-decimal"})
price_2 = str(price_2).split("<span class=\"product-price-decimal\">")[1]
price_2 = price_2.split("</span>")[0]
price_3 = (price + "," +  price_2)
product = brand + price_3
print(product)
for i in range(24):
        print(product)
```

as said, it does print 24 lines. but instead of listing all the different ones, it just lists the first result (probably because the i = 0). i'm very bad at coding so I don't know what to change to get the wanted result. any thoughts?

Comment: Well, you don't change the `product` in your loop at all. Of course, it will print the same thing. And just a note: `range(24)` is the same as `range(0, 24, 1)`.

Comment: right, and to do that i need something to change the i right? how do i do that?

Comment: Changing the `i` won't change `product` (and `i` does change each iteration, it is 0 at first, then 1, then 2, etc.). Could you send a page URL to understand what you are parsing?

Comment: of course! i just picked a random one:
https://www.gamma.nl/assortiment/l/hout/bouwhout/hardhout

Comment: Please post the html along with your question. Some users won't feel comfortable going to other websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = "https://www.gamma.nl/assortiment/l/hout/bouwhout/hardhout"
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.select("article.mc-product-tile"):
    print("title : " + item.select_one("div.product-name a").text)
    print("Price : " + item.select_one("div.wishlist-icon")['data-productprice'].strip())
```

**Output:**

```
title : Lat hardhout geschaafd wit gegrond 9x116 mm 210 cm
Price : 16.99
title : Lat geschaafd hardhout 12x55 mm 210 cm
Price : 8.49
title : Lat hardhout geschaafd 20x28 mm 210 cm
Price : 9.59
title : Plank eiken 19x195 mm 250 cm
Price : 29.49
title : Lat hardhout geschaafd 28x44 mm 210 cm
Price : 14.99
title : Lat hardhout geschaafd 9x116 mm 210 cm
Price : 14.99
title : Lat hardhout geschaafd wit gegrond 12x68 mm 210 cm
Price : 14.99
title : Lat hardhout geschaafd 20x44 mm 210 cm
Price : 12.49
title : Glaslat hardhout wit gegrond 17x28 mm 270 cm
Price : 10.99
title : Lat hardhout geschaafd wit gegrond 12x44 mm 210 cm
Price : 9.99
title : Lat hardhout geschaafd 12x68 mm 210 cm
Price : 12.99
title : Lat hardhout geschaafd 20x68 mm 210 cm
Price : 15.99
title : Lat hardhout geschaafd 9x35 mm 210 cm
Price : 6.79
title : Lat geschaafd hardhout 12x12 mm 270 cm
Price : 3.29
title : Lat hardhout geschaafd 12x35 mm 210 cm
Price : 8.29
title : Lat geschaafd hardhout 9x44 mm 270 cm
Price : 7.49
title : Lat geschaafd hardhout 12x27 mm 270 cm
Price : 6.99
title : Lat hardhout geschaafd 12x116 mm 210 cm
Price : 19.49
title : Lat hardhout geschaafd 9x28 mm 210 cm
Price : 4.49
title : Lat hardhout geschaafd 44x44 mm 210 cm
Price : 24.99
title : Lat geschaafd hardhout 12x44 mm 270 cm
Price : 8.99
title : Lat geschaafd hardhout 9x27 mm 270 cm
Price : 5.19
title : Lat hardhout geschaafd 44 x 68 mm 210 cm
Price : 43.98
title : Lat hardhout geschaafd 20x116 mm 210 cm
Price : 34.95
```

Comment: it says "no module named requests" where is this module from?

Comment: did you import requests module?

Comment: yes; Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fuck2.py", line 2, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests

Comment: Go to command prompt type `pip install requests` Once it is install successfully you will be able to run the code.

Comment: one more question (learning myself to program and i'm pretty bad at it). since the resutls are in a print form, is there anyway i can still do things with them? E.G. list them or organize them or something. i currently don't know how to select them (because they're a print)

Comment: Yes,Declare empty list of title and price and append the values in each iteration.